# android gson parser

Tags: android, gson

Как создать такую структуру классов модели из вот такого приходящего gson? Собственно нужна сериализация и десериализация.

```
Elements:[
{
  …,
   “type”: “category”,
   …,
   elements:[
   {
      …,
      “type”: “item”,
      ...
   }]
}, {
   ...
}]
```

Comment: какую «такую»? уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

```
AllElements = new JSONArray();

JSONObject Elements = new JSONObject();
Elements.put("type", "category");
JSONObject elements = new JSONObject();
elements.put("type", "item");
Elements.put("elements", elements);

AllElements.put(Elements);
JSONObject outPut = new JSONObject();
outPut.put("Elements", AllElements);
```